# How to put numbers $1$ to $8$ in a row that every number shouldn't be bigger than the sum of numbers next to it?

Tags: combinatorics

How to put numbers $1$ to $8$ in a row that every number shouldn't be bigger than the sum of numbers next to it?

**My attempt**: I tried to put numbers from left to right and count the ways but it was to hard and didn't give the answer.Any hints(not answers).

Comment: Sum of how many next numbers?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh one right one left

Comment: Then where you want to place 8?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh sorry that was bigger.

Comment: Whenever you put $\;8\;$ it will break the rule for *at least* one other number...

Comment: @DonAntonio   Why? you can put $8$ between $6$ and $7$.

Comment: Are you looking for every solution, or just one solution?

Comment: @LouisB number of solutions.

Comment: @TahaAkbari Then automatically the rule is broken both for $\;6\;$ and $\;7\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio        This is one type:$1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7$

Comment: @TahaAkbari But then the sum of the numbers next to $\;6\;$ is much higher than $\;6\;$ ...Am I missing something? BTW, also for $\;8\;$ this rule is broken...and for $\;2,3\;$ and **all** the others. Either I misunderstood something big time or else you didn't write the correct exercise.

Comment: Mathematica found $3512$ solutions.

Comment: @DonAntonio   shouldn't be bigger than the sum of numbers next to it(can be smaller or equal.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter The answer in the book is$128$.

Comment: @Taha I think I got it now: the number itself cannot be bigger than the sum, not the other way around....but only after you **changed** the word "smaller" by "bigger" in your post :)

Comment: On just three integers, there are only two acceptable orderings: $\{1,3,2\}$ and $\{2,3,1\}$, correct? $\{3,1,2\},~\{2,1,3\}$ are not acceptable because $3>1$ and $\{1,2,3\},~\{3,2,1\}$ are not acceptable because $3>2$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the first three numbers satisfy the condition, but the whole seqence does not.

Since $1+2+3+4>8$ we must necessarily have $a_4>a_1+a_2+a_3$.

Case $1: a_4=7$, in this case we must have that $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are a permutation of $1,2,3$. So there are $3!\times 4!$ counterexamples of this form.

Case $2: a_4=8$, In this case we can have that $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are a permutation of $1,2,3$ or $1,2,4$. In total there are $2\times 3!\times 4!$ counterexamples.

---

So how many permutations satisfy that $a_1>a_2$ and $a_1+a_2>a_3$. Since clearly the two conditions are independent we must only count the triples $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ with $a_1>a_2$ with $a_1+a_2<a_3$.

They can be enumerated rather quickly:

$(1,a,k)$ gives $5+4+3+2+1=15$ solutions.

$(2,a,k)$ gives $3+2+1=6$ solutions.

$(3,a,k)$ gives $1$ solution.

So there are $22$ solutions.

This means that there are $\frac{8\times 7 \times 6 - 2\times 22}{2}$ triples that satisfy $a_1<a_2$ and $a_1+a_2\geq a_3$. So our final answer is:

$$\frac{8\times 7 \times 6 - 2\times 22}{2}\times 5!-3\times 3!\times 4!$$